# Understanding .reduce() function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can someone explain this code?

I get the .concat and the .map function but I'm confuse why there's two .reduce method in order to print out all the possible permutations of the different vectors.

```
var arr = [['red','blue','pink'],['dog','cat','bird'],['loud', 'quiet']],
    res = arr.reduce((p,c) => p.reduce((r,x) => r.concat(c.map(y => x + " " + y)),[]));
console.log(res);
```

What does the two .reduce method do?

Comment: first reduces arr[], second reduces each array inside arr[]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: There's two `.reduce()` because there are nested arrays.  The first one iterates the outer array.  The second one iterates each of the inner arrays.  It would be like having nested `.forEach()` calls for a similar reason to traverse every element of every sub-array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reduce try to turn an array into 1 single item by traversing each item in a reducer (reducer is a function).

in your example
arr is going to be reduced by the **reducer** 
(p,c) => p.reduce((r,x) => r.concat(c.map(y => x + " " + y)),[])

this reducer contained another reducer which contains a **reducer** 
(r,x) => r.concat(c.map(y => x + " " + y)),**[]**

this reducer did 2 different things to incoming items which are concat and map, also it has an initial value **[]** (means it starts to traverse the item to the reducer from an empty array)
concat is to merge an array
map is to execute the defined operation for every items in the subject

thus, the full operation can be elaborated as below. executing this code can also see the log on how the statements ran sequentially on 2 reducer

```
var arr = [['red','blue','pink'],['dog','cat','bird'],['loud', 'quiet']],
    res = arr.reduce(
            (p,c) => {
                console.log("first reducer",p,c);
            return p.reduce(
                (r,x) => {
                        console.log("second reducer",r,x);
                        return r.concat(c.map(y => {
                                        console.log("map",x,y); 
                                        return x + " " + y;}));
                        }
                ,[])
            }
        );
console.log("ans",res);
```

the result of the reduction process

```
VM928:4 first reducer ["red", "blue", "pink"] ["dog", "cat", "bird"]
VM928:7 second reducer [] red
VM928:9 map red dog
VM928:9 map red cat
VM928:9 map red bird
VM928:7 second reducer ["red dog", "red cat", "red bird"] blue
VM928:9 map blue dog
VM928:9 map blue cat
VM928:9 map blue bird
VM928:7 second reducer ["red dog", "red cat", "red bird", "blue dog", "blue cat", "blue bird"] pink
VM928:9 map pink dog
VM928:9 map pink cat
VM928:9 map pink bird
VM928:4 first reducer ["red dog", "red cat", "red bird", "blue dog", "blue cat", "blue bird", "pink dog", "pink cat", "pink bird"] ["loud", "quiet"]
VM928:7 second reducer [] red dog
VM928:9 map red dog loud
VM928:9 map red dog quiet
VM928:7 second reducer ["red dog loud", "red dog quiet"] red cat
VM928:9 map red cat loud
VM928:9 map red cat quiet
VM928:7 second reducer ["red dog loud", "red dog quiet", "red cat loud", "red cat quiet"] red bird
VM928:9 map red bird loud
VM928:9 map red bird quiet
VM928:7 second reducer ["red dog loud", "red dog quiet", "red cat loud", "red cat quiet", "red bird loud", "red bird quiet"] blue dog
VM928:9 map blue dog loud
VM928:9 map blue dog quiet
VM928:7 second reducer ["red dog loud", "red dog quiet", "red cat loud", "red cat quiet", "red bird loud", "red bird quiet", "blue dog loud", "blue dog quiet"] blue cat
VM928:9 map blue cat loud
VM928:9 map blue cat quiet
VM928:7 second reducer ["red dog loud", "red dog quiet", "red cat loud", "red cat quiet", "red bird loud", "red bird quiet", "blue dog loud", "blue dog quiet", "blue cat loud", "blue cat quiet"] blue bird
VM928:9 map blue bird loud
VM928:9 map blue bird quiet
VM928:7 second reducer ["red dog loud", "red dog quiet", "red cat loud", "red cat quiet", "red bird loud", "red bird quiet", "blue dog loud", "blue dog quiet", "blue cat loud", "blue cat quiet", "blue bird loud", "blue bird quiet"] pink dog
VM928:9 map pink dog loud
VM928:9 map pink dog quiet
VM928:7 second reducer ["red dog loud", "red dog quiet", "red cat loud", "red cat quiet", "red bird loud", "red bird quiet", "blue dog loud", "blue dog quiet", "blue cat loud", "blue cat quiet", "blue bird loud", "blue bird quiet", "pink dog loud", "pink dog quiet"] pink cat
VM928:9 map pink cat loud
VM928:9 map pink cat quiet
VM928:7 second reducer ["red dog loud", "red dog quiet", "red cat loud", "red cat quiet", "red bird loud", "red bird quiet", "blue dog loud", "blue dog quiet", "blue cat loud", "blue cat quiet", "blue bird loud", "blue bird quiet", "pink dog loud", "pink dog quiet", "pink cat loud", "pink cat quiet"] pink bird
VM928:9 map pink bird loud
VM928:9 map pink bird quiet
VM928:15 ans ["red dog loud", "red dog quiet", "red cat loud", "red cat quiet", "red bird loud", "red bird quiet", "blue dog loud", "blue dog quiet", "blue cat loud", "blue cat quiet", "blue bird loud", "blue bird quiet", "pink dog loud", "pink dog quiet", "pink cat loud", "pink cat quiet", "pink bird loud", "pink bird quiet"]
```

Consequently, the reduction process arr.reduce((p,c)=>p(c)) is reducing the array's array into 1 array by reducer p((r,x)=>r(x)),

the reducer p((r,x)=>r(x)) tries to concat and map one by one from the most inner items, however, **map** is using **x** in the formula (x is an 1X3 array), it caused the size of the array didn't reduced (as mapping an array(1x3) and an array(1x1) means an array(1x3) is returned ) after the reduction process is done.

Comment: Thanks! this made it really clear seeing how it worked step by step!

Answer (score 1):

Lamdas let you not name things

```
var arr = [['red','blue','pink'],['dog','cat','bird'],['loud', 'quiet']];

function permutations (fullArray, innerArray) {
  return fullArray.reduce(traverseInner, []);
  function traverseInner (list, currentText) {
    console.log(list, currentText);
    return list.concat(innerArray.map(append));
    function append (additionalText) {
      return `${currentText} ${additionalText}`;
    }
  }
}

var res = arr.reduce(permutations);
console.log(res);
```

This is my take on it expanded, with an inner console.log that make it easier to see it in progress.